# Visual Studio for Arduino - Deep Search Issue

Tags: arduino-uno, visualstudio

Finally got some time to play with my Arduino. I downloaded the Arduino editor and wrote a quick sketch which worked fine.

I then downloaded the Visual Studio extension from  VisuaMicro. I configured it to point towards my Arduino directory, which in my case is : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt

I created a new Arduino project and copied the same sketch it. When I try to build it I get errors as below:

```
Compiling debug version of 'Sketch1' for 'Arduino/Genuino Uno'
Build Folder: 
file:///C:/Users/bbbsb/AppData/Local/Temp/VMBuilds/Sketch1/uno/Debug
Additional Defines: VM_DEBUG;VM_DEBUG_ENABLE 
1;VM_DEBUG_BANDWIDTH_THROTTLE_MS 50;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL 
0;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_SOFTWARESERIAL 1;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_FASTSERIAL 
2;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USB 3;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_TEENSY 4;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_UART 
5;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USART 6;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USBSERIAL 
7;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_TTYUART 8;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_NET_CONSOLE 
9;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_Uart 10;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_COSA 
11;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_CDCSerialClass 12;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL1 
13;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL2 14;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL3 
15;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_NET_UDP 16;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USBAPI 
17;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_SERIALUSB 18;VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE 
VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL;VM_DEBUG_BREAKPAUSE;
Architecture Tools: 
file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/
ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt/hardware/tools/avr/bin/
Api: 1.1706.25-9.061
Sketch Book: file:///C:/Users/bbbsb/Documents/Arduino
Sketch Include Paths
Core Include Paths
Include Path     file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino
Include Path     file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard
Searching for libraries ...
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DVM_DEBUG_BREAKPAUSE -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE=VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_SERIALUSB=18 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USBAPI=17 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_NET_UDP=16 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL3=15 -            
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL2=14 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL1=13 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_CDCSerialClass=12 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_COSA=11  -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_Uart=10 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_NET_CONSOLE=9 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_TTYUART=8 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USBSERIAL=7 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USART=6 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_UART=5 -        
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_TEENSY=4 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USB=3 -    
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_FASTSERIAL=2 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_SOFTWARESERIAL=1 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL=0 -DVM_DEBUG_BANDWIDTH_THROTTLE_MS=50 -
DVM_DEBUG_ENABLE=1 -DVM_DEBUG   -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805  -
DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" -I"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\bbbsb\AppData\Local\Temp\VMBuilds\Sketch1\uno\Debug\Sketch1.cpp" -o "nul"
Access is denied
Preprocess: "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DVM_DEBUG_BREAKPAUSE -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE=VM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_SERIALUSB=18 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USBAPI=17 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_NET_UDP=16 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL3=15 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL2=14 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL1=13 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_CDCSerialClass=12 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_COSA=11 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_Uart=10 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_NET_CONSOLE=9 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_TTYUART=8 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USBSERIAL=7 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USART=6 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_UART=5 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_TEENSY=4 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_USB=3 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_FASTSERIAL=2 -DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_SOFTWARESERIAL=1 -
DVM_DEBUGGER_TYPE_HARDWARESERIAL=0 -DVM_DEBUG_BANDWIDTH_THROTTLE_MS=50 -
DVM_DEBUG_ENABLE=1 -DVM_DEBUG   -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -
DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I"C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" -I"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\bbbsb\AppData\Local\Temp\VMBuilds\Sketch1\uno\Debug\Sketch1.cpp" -o "nul"
Object reference not set to an instance of an object



An error was encountered during the 'Deep Search' library discovery process.
```

Debug build failed for project 'Sketch1'

I've obviously not setup something correctly but cnnot work out what?
Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that you're using the Windows App Store version of the Arduino IDE. Windows puts some strange restrictions on the C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt folder that the Windows Store version of the Arduino IDE is installed to. Please try uninstalling this App thing and instead use the standard IDE downloaded from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well, you have to "import" the libraries for your project from within Visual Micro.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just tried it as per1234 suggested: installed the full windows version (not the windows app version), configured the VS extension accordingly and now it builds (same code).